# Parallel Transport of Tangent Vectors in O(n)

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

Since $O(n)$ emits a bi-invariant (Riemannian) metric, geodesics emanating from the identity coincide precisely with one-parameter subgroups, that is, the curves $t \mapsto \exp(tX)$ for X in the Lie algebra. And we can translate this geodesic to emanate from any point in $O(n)$ with just left multiplication. The geodesic emanating from, say, $Q \in O(n)$ is the curve $\gamma(t) = Q\exp(tX)$, with  $t \in [0,1]$ and $X \in T_{Q}O(n)$, i.e. $X = QB$ for some skew-symmetric matrix $B$.

I'm interested in computing the parallel transport of $X$. What is the tangent vector at $\gamma(t)$ that is parallel to $X$? I'm aware that I need to compute $\nabla_{d/dt \gamma(t)} X(t)$ with $X(0) = X$, where $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection but I keep getting stuck on this time and time again.

I appreciate any and all help here. Thanks so much.

Comment: Perhaps it would help to relate the connection (Christoffel symbols) to the structure constants of the Lie algebra/group.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm sure. Have you worked with the Christoffel symbols on O(n)? I was hoping I could use $\nabla_XY = 1/2[X,Y]$. I think this is for all $X, Y$ in the Lie algebra?

Comment: It should amount to the same thing. Have you started by doing $SO(3)$? (Yes, that's for invariant vector fields.) So now what?